# Routing a component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, url-routing

I'm thinking of building a knockout routing engine which **loads knockout "components" on demand** based on the url parameters, **not on matching predefined routes** values like in 99% of the examples.
The reason i need this is that i'll have different amount of views and components based on conditions.

For the components the task was easy i just followed some examples and the following works fine for me:

```
ko.components.loaders.push({
    getConfig: function(name, callback) {
        var componentPieces,
            componentName,
            componentNamespace

        if( name && name.indexOf('-') >= 1){
            componentPieces = name.split('-');
            componentName = componentPieces[1];
            componentNamespace = componentPieces[0];
            callback({
                viewModel: {
                    require: "components/" + componentNamespace + "/" + componentName + "ViewModel"
                },
                template: {
                    require: "text!components/" + componentNamespace + "/" + componentName + ".tmpl.html"
                }
            })

        }else{
            callback(null);
        }
    },
    //use the default loaders functionality for loading
    loadComponent: ko.components.defaultLoader.loadComponent
});
```

So far so good, but i'm experiencing difficulties with the routing engine and i'm looking for solutions.
At the moment this one looks promising but i kind of don't feel it

```
define(["knockout", "crossroads", "hasher"], function(ko, crossroads, hasher) {

    var routerConfig = {
        defaultParams: { page: 'home', action: 'view' }
    };

    function Router(config) {
        var self = this;
        var currentRoute = self.currentRoute = ko.observable({});

        crossroads.addRoute(':page:/:action:', function(requestParams) {
            var routeParams = $.extend(config.defaultParams, requestParams);
            self.currentRoute(routeParams);
        });
        crossroads.bypassed.add(function(){
            self.error(404);
        });
        self.error = function(code){
            self.currentRoute({ page: 'error', code: code });
        };

        startCrossroads();
    }

    function startCrossroads() {
        function parseHash(newHash, oldHash) { crossroads.parse(newHash); }
        crossroads.normalizeFn = crossroads.NORM_AS_OBJECT;
        // crossroads.shouldTypecast = true;
        hasher.initialized.add(parseHash);
        hasher.changed.add(parseHash);
        hasher.init();
    }

    return new Router(routerConfig);
});
```

Any helpful resources and ides will be very appreciated.

Comment: Check out this nice [tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail). It describes Knockout + SammyJs application, which may fit your needs pretty well.

Comment: I played around with this for a while, but I didn't get anything I liked.  Take a look at this code and edit your question with your first attempt.  Then you will get more useful answers because people will have a starting point:

https://github.com/milimetric/dashiki/blob/7f17f5ec9fac261ec197d02a86430ccf40b3dd7b/src/app/router.js

This is a modification of this demo, which you should watch: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/

Answer (score 0):

Check my blog post here

http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/08/11/single-page-application-with-sub-routing/

It has a main id for the viewmodel to load `#MyMainModel`

And then it also listen to sub routs using the query after the hash like

```
#MyMainModel?id=5
```

I cant really say if its a 100% solution for your usecase but maybe it can give you some pointers?